# Extract Excel Metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, metadata

Is there a method or feature available in Excel that allows the extraction of file metadata from the content of an Excel file, similar to the functionality provided by Word's "Insert > Quick Parts > Document Property" feature?

Answer (score 0):

There is the property promotion/demotion for Office properties.
The column names in SharePoint need to exactly match the property names in the Office file.
There are also 3rd party apps that provide extraction functionality when uploading an Office file but this is one-way only.
Not sure what PowerAutomate can offer. Hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: Thanks Paul. What 3rd party apps can do this? Syntex?

Comment: Syntax can probably also handle this. 
See here (https://collab365.com/best-document-management-solutions-for-sharepoint/) for a list with document management tools for SharePoint. There are probably multiple tools with the capability. I do know the Explorer tool provides functionality to extract properties from files (msg, eml, pdf, docx, xlsx, jpg, mp4, ...) during uploading and capture the values into SharePoint columns.